# Component SQL Updates Not Running

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, extension-update, joomla-3.7

I have been troubleshooting this all morning and am stuck. Hoping someone can help. Using Joomla! 3.7.0.

I have a component that contains a number of MySQL update files. These files have been working flawlessly until now. In administrator/components/com_example/sql/updates/mysql/ there are files for every version of my extension from 1.0.0 to 1.0.10 (the current version).

I can verify that every update script ran as expected when the component was updated up to version 1.0.7 (both 1.0.8 and 1.0.9 were just placeholders that contained no database changes). For whatever reason, the update file for 1.0.10 is not running. No error is thrown. I have copied the (very basic) SQL into PHPMyAdmin and it runs without issue.

What could be suddenly causing my SQL updates not to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out. There was a bad version number in the #__schemas table. I rolled that version number back to a valid one and the updates work again.